# Continuous process is measurable

Tags: stochastic-processes, measurable-functions, filtrations

I am revising the lecture notes and i stumbled across this proposition:

> Given $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ a probability space, the following holds:
>
> 1. If a process $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ has continuous trajectories (that is the map $t\to X_t$ is continuous), then it is measurable (that is $X\colon(\Omega\times[0,\infty),\mathcal{A}\otimes\mathcal{B}([0,\infty)))\to(\mathbb{R}^{d},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{d}))$ is measurable),
> 2. If  $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is also adapted to a filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq 0}$ then it is progressively measurable w.r.t. $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq 0}$

In class, we proved the second claim, using the following method: fixed $T>0$, we defined
$$X^n_t=\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}X_{\frac{k}{2^n}T}\, 1_{\left[\frac{k-1}{2^n}T,\frac{k}{2^n}T\right)}(t)+X_T\,1_{\{T\}}(t)$$
Since it is all $\mathcal{F}_T$-measurable, then we have that $X^n$ is measurable (as a process). Then, thanks to the continuity of the trajectories, we have that $$\forall t\in [0,T], \forall\omega\in\Omega, \quad X_t^n(\omega)\rightarrow X_t(\omega)\quad\text{as }n\rightarrow +\infty$$
and this basically gives us the thesis.

Now our professor said that the first claim is to be demonstrated in a similar way, but i don't really know how to start. Can someone answer me or give me an hint?

Comment: The first part is already contained in the second part.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you for your comment. Why is that so?

Comment: What i don't understand is that, in the second part, to show the measurability of $X^n$ we actively use the fact that $X$ is adapted; in the first part this is not possible.

Comment: Apply second part with $\mathcal F_t$ defined as $\sigma (X_s: s\le t)$

Comment: @geetha290krm ahh, i thinked about it but it felt like cheating. Thanks a lot for your help.